# Excel 2010 VBA Backslash (\) Operator

Tags: excel, vba

In learning VBA, every source I read tells me that the `\` operator performs integer division. So I was thinking I could use it to extract the integer part of a floating point number.

I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
A = 5
B = 50%
```

I need to compute: `C = A x B`, rounded down to the nearest integer (ie, any 2.01, 2.1, 2.9, 2.99 etc. all should be rounded down to 2).

I was thinking I could do this:

```
C = (A * B) \ 1
```

But it doesn't work - it appears to me that the float part is rounded up (i.e., 2.25 is taken to 3) before performing the integer division.

I have right now done this:

```
 C = (A * B - 0.5) \ 1
```

which doesn't work in some cases (where `A * B` is exactly equal to an integer, likely representation issues).

What else can I do?

Comment: What you have written now makes little sense, because you say you want to "round all of them **down to 3**" and then you are pointing that rounding 2.25 to 3 is wrong.. Make your mind! Is 3 wrong or not? 2.01 is not 'nearest' to 3, and the 3 is not even down from 2. Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding for the naming of the rounding modes and don't use verb "round down" if you mean simply "to round" because it will introduce confusion. If you must work with financial/fiscal rounding, remember that it is "to-even" (so not '3'), and call it "to-even", "fiscal" or "statistically-safe".

Comment: @Wolfie Oh come on, I was about to answer this and then realised it was asked six years ago.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup I came across it whilst looking for an answer, saw the typo and bad formatting and left the place tidier than I found it for future readers. You are still welcome to provide a better answer than the ones already here.

Answer (score 0):

Duh. It appears I could have done:

Int(A * B)

to get what I wanted.

Comment: so, you have meant TRUNCATE or ROUND:CLOSEST-TO-ZERO?

Answer (score 0):

be careful:

```
any 2.01, 2.1, 2.9, 2.99 etc. all should be rounded down to 3
```

Then you are not looking for the `nearest integer`, but the ceiling function. Nearest integer sounds like Round or Fix functions (you have homework now: look for the differences between them both!)

For the ceiling function, take a look here:

Ceiling function used as in Excel:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/612151-how-to-use-standard-excel-function-in-vba.html

Code for VBA ceiling function:

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5031